# Pascal's triangle in c with recursive functions

Tags: c

Hi this is my code for calculating pascal triangle but it runs error : has stopped working... why ?
i think its error is in paskal function

```
#include <stdio.h>

long paskal(int,int);

int main (void)
{
    int  n = 0 ;
    int m = 0 ;
    int k  = 0 ;

    scanf("%d" , &n);

    for(k = 1  ; n >= k ;   )
    {
        for(  m = 1 ; k >= m   ; m++ )
        {
            long f = paskal(k , m ) ;
            printf("%ld" , f);
        }
        printf("\n");
        k++;
    }

     return 0; 
}

long paskal( int n , int i ) 
{
    if(n == 1 && i == 1 )
        return 1 ; 
    else
        return paskal(n-1,i) + paskal(n-1,i-1);
}
```

Comment: `khayam` is non-terminating for any `i` not equaling to `1`. Check your logic.

Comment: could u please say how can i fix it?

Comment: I'd suggest to add some space between consecutive numbers printed in a row with `for(m...)` loop. In the next improved version you may try to align rows to some vertical center line (but that would require some estimation of a single numer width.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems with your code like the recursion termination condition:

```
if(n == 1 && i == 1 )
```

which is not correct and lead to recurse the function forever and ultimately the program will terminate abnormally.

Moreover, if you fix this condition, you are not going to get the Pascal triangle as output because both the `for` loops in `main()` is initializing the loop variable with `1` which will eat up the first column of every row of pascal triangle.

For the terminating condition of recursive function `paskal()` -

In the function `long paskal( int n , int i )`, the `n` is representing the row whereas the `i` represent the column in that particular row and `pascal()` function is supposed to calculate the element at a particular location.

A couple of points, in Pascal triangle:

1. The leftmost and rightmost element of every row is `1`.
2. Every row contains the number of columns same as the row number.

So, I can say -

```
if(n == i || i == 0) //i.e. if ((row == col) || (col == 0)) return 1;
    return 1;
```

could be terminating condition of the recursive function.

Collectively, your program will be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long paskal(int, int);

int main() {
   int n = 0;
   int m = 0;
   int k = 0;
   int s = 0;
   printf ("Enter number of rows:\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   for(k = 0; n >= k; k++) {
            for(s = 0; s < n-k; s++) //Add spaces before each row
                    printf(" ");
            for(m = 0; k >= m; m++) {
                    long f = paskal(k, m);
                    printf("%ld ", f);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

long paskal(int n, int i) {
        if(n == i || i == 0)
                return 1;
        else
                return paskal(n-1, i) + paskal(n-1, i-1);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The limit-conditions are not correct.

The correct way to put the limit conditions is

```
if(n == 1 || i == 1 )
    return 1 ; 
else
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to account for cases where i>n and where i or n = 0:

```
long paskal( int n , int i ) 
{
if(i<0 || n<0 || i>n) return 0;
if(n == 1)
    return 1 ; 
else

    return paskal(n-1,i) + paskal(n-1,i-1);
}
```

Comment: This code makes a symmetric "triangle" of numbers, instead of just going to the highest number in each row (though it may be hard to tell the divisions between numbers that aren't single-digit!).

Comment: Not necessary. But if you insist testing for unexpected conditions, why don't you test for negative values...?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

long paskal(int,int);

int main (void)
{
    int  n = 0 ;
    int m = 0 ;
    int k  = 0 ;

    scanf("%d" , &n);

    for(k = 0  ; k<n ;   )
    {
        for(  m = 0 ; m<k   ; m++ )
        {
            long f = paskal(k , m ) ;
            printf("%ld" , f);
        }
        printf("\n");
        k++;
    }

     return 0; 
}

long paskal( int n , int i ) 
{
    if(i == 1 || n == i )
        return 1 ; 
    else
        return paskal(n-1,i) + paskal(n-1,i-1);
}
```

You had some errors in your code. Now your code will work.

Comment: Does this add anything over the accepted answer that was posted in 2017? If so, you should add some explanation as to how your code improves the accepted answer.