# Convert C code into MATLAB code? Regarding Pascal's triangle and recursive functions

Tags: c, matlab

Can someone help convert the C code below into matlab. I've never done C and just a beginner at MATLAB. Below is the code - note: it does not belong to me, I took it from [Pascal's triangle in c with recursive functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397947/pascals-triangle-in-c-with-recursive-functions)

```
#include <stdio.h>

long paskal(int, int);

int main() {
   int n = 0;
   int m = 0;
   int k = 0;
   int s = 0;
   printf ("Enter number of rows:\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   for(k = 0; n >= k; k++) {
            for(s = 0; s < n-k; s++) //Add spaces before each row
                    printf(" ");
            for(m = 0; k >= m; m++) {
                    long f = paskal(k, m);
                    printf("%ld ", f);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

long paskal(int n, int i) {
        if(n == i || i == 0)
                return 1;
        else
                return paskal(n-1, i) + paskal(n-1, i-1);
}
```

This is my attempt, I've tried but I'm a beginner at MATLAB too so I got quite stuck. The overall idea is to get a a working code of pascals triangle using recursive functions.

```
function [ A ] = getpascal( n )


m = 0;
k = 0; 
s = 0;

for k == 0 && n >= k
    for s= = 0 && s < n-k
        disp( "s")
        for m == 0; k >= m
            f = getpascal(k,m);
        end
    end
    return 0;
    
      
    
end
getpascal(n , i)
if n == 1 || i == 0
    A = 1;
else
    return getpascal(n-1, i) + getpascal(n-1, i-1);
end
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: "Invalid use of operator"  at the first for loop. And if I remove an equals sign, I get "Incorrect use of '=' operator. To assign a value to a variable, use '='.
To compare values for equality, use '=='."

Comment: `n = 0;` will overwrite the input argument

Comment: In c++ `>=` is also an invalid operator!  Also you are missing an `end`

Answer (score 0):

The for loop in MATLAB is different. You can replace the for loops as:

```
for k=0:n
   for s=0:n-k-1
      for m=0:k
      end
   end
end
```